# Erlang:Client ip-address, send packet to specific client?

Tags: erlang, client, ip-address, tcp

Is there a way to get the ip-address of a client in Erlang for a tcp connection; based on the assumption that the client connects to the server?

I'm also wondering if its ever necessary to send particular packets to specific clients; as in the case where the server isn't broadcasting, but would I need the ip-address to send packets to a specific client or does the server simply use a reference (erlang:monitor) for each client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Address at the other end, [`inet:peername(Socket)`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#peername-1). However, if you want to handle each client in a `TCP Conversation`, once each client connects, usually, you would spawn separate erlang process to handle that, and then [`Transfer the Socket Ownership`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#controlling_process-2) to the spawned process. 
Then, within the `receive loop`, you would send and receive binary data to/from the client. Consider looking at this module: [`gen_tcp`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html),  in details.  However, your question sounds like, you want to implement a `Peer-to-peer` system. In such systems, you would create `agents` within the software, with each agent capable of being a server or a client at any time. This is especially required when communication between the agents will be only on demand and that sessions/connections will not be created unless there is something to send. I probably should not go into that.